# Program to create and manage session-like 'bundles' of documents and webpages

Tags: windows, file-management, batch

I am looking for a program to create 'bundles' or groups of documents and webpages, similarly to Windows desktops but without needing to define new desktops. Also similarly to the typical 'save for later' extensions for web browsers, but running on your operating system, not on your browser.

Example/Use case: I am working on a subject, using several files (Word, Excel, PDF documents, programming code in my preferred GUI, websites...) and I want to stop and continue working on it later. I would like to save that current session in a sort of `.BAT` file that I can execute later to open all those documents again.

Ideally, I should be able to select which opened files must be included in a new 'bundle'. Furthermore, these bundles should be able to be modified, deleted, etc.

Is there any program that can do this in (at least) Windows OS?

---

EDIT

I expand my request. I could also be interested in saving folders (from my hard drives) in a bundle so that they should be reopened when 'calling' that bundle.

**A possible way to do this:** I think this could be done by creating a **new folder for each new bundle** and adding **shortcuts into this new folder.** When I want to go back to the task, I just need to go to this folder and open all the shortcuts in it. So, I would be only needing a way to 'send' some of my open documents to this new folder.

---

EDIT

One of the comments below made me think further about what I am really asking. I do not need to 'hibernate' my opened programs, meaning that I do not need them to be opened in the very same position, aspect, or setting as I left them. **I just need not to have to remember all the programs, folders and websites I had opened when I was working in a given task.**

Comment: If I understand you correctly you search for a way to save the state of multiple open applications so that you can later restore it. The problem in saving the state of a application without support by the application itself is very difficult because there are open files and other relations to the OS. See als this question in SuperUser https://superuser.com/questions/275010/can-i-hibernate-a-program The only feasible way is using a virtual machine with an own OS. Such a machine can be suspended at any time and later restored.

Comment: @Robert It is more or less like that, yes. But I don't mind if the application is not exactly in the same 'position' than it was when I left it. For instance, if I was editing a Word document, it is OK to me if the document is opened again when I go back to open the bundle, no matter if the last edit position was not saved.

So, I am thinking of just a quick way to save my open documents, apps and folders, and 'reopen' them. Therefore, I assume that I cannot 'hibernate' them but rather close and then reopen them later.